# Execute Nextflow process after all other processes

Tags: nextflow

My DSL 2 nexflow; the goal is to execute elapsed_time AFTER all other process steps. elapsed_time has no dependency on other process steps.

```
process elapsed_time {
    input:
        val sra 
        
    script:
    """
    echo "Elapsed time for ${sra} is calculated here"
    """
}
workflow {
    println "params.sra=${params.sra}"

    // prefetch using http direct; do not use sra toolkit
    result_prefetch = prefetch_http(params.sra)
    result_prefetch.sra_value.view()  {"SRA=[${it}]"} 

    // perform fasterq dump
    result_fasterqdump = fasterqdump(params.sra, result_prefetch.sra)
    result_fasterqdump.fastq.view() println { it }

    // elapsed_time process executes after prefetch_http and fasterqdump
    elapsed_time(params.sra).after(result_prefetch, result_fasterqdump)
}
```

Last Line **elapsed_time** causes this error:

```
Missing process or function after([[DataflowVariable(value=null), DataflowVariable(value=null)], [DataflowVariable(value=null)]])
```